# How many drop tunings can I use with one set of strings?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, instruments

I want to know how many drop tunings I can reasonably use with one set of strings. 
Ex. can I go from E standard to drop C on 11s?
For a given size string, how many tunings will be useable, given that E standard has to be the highest one? In the best case, I would like to go down to drop B or drop A. Is that feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is feasible, yes. Your challenge will come from the low tension you will require on that bottom string. Using standard strings will mean a much lower tension than if you use thicker strings.

Effects of lower tension include:

- tuning is difficult. Any extra pressure in the string will pull it up out of tune
- slapping against the fretboard and catching on the edge of the pickups
- truss rod adjustments required to match tension

Going down to a drop A is a pretty major drop, so I would suggest that unless you like the slappy type of sound and are very light with your fretting hand you will want to go up one or two gauges on this string.

Comment: I already use 11s as my normal strings because I play a lot of metal and like the tight response. Are 11s big enough?

Comment: From my experience 11s are fine for your top five strings (and fine for a drop d) but you will want to go up a gauge or two for your bottom string.

Comment: See this question that you just inspired: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/7498/can-i-split-guitar-string-gauges

Comment: And @Alex's answer is spot on. Just changing one string is much less of an issue.